# angularjs: transforming comma separated list to unordered list ng-repeat

Tags: arrays, angularjs, split, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an array called data.list that stores a list of mandatory and optional appointments:

```
data.list.push({
  mandatory: appt.getDisplayValue('mandatory_appointments'),
  optional: appt.getDisplayValue('optional_appointments')
});
```

Mandatory and Optional returns a comma separate list of appointments that looks like this:

appointment1, appointment2, appointment3, appointment4, etc...

For my HTML, I wanted to use ng-repeat to produce a list of mandatory and optional tasks that looks like this:

appointment1

appointment2

appointment3

appointment4

What do I need to change in order to achieve this?

```
<div ng-repeat="item in c.list track by $index">
   {{item.mandatory}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the values of the mandatory and optional are strings and separated by comma(,). You need to use `string.split(",")` to generate an array.

See this fiddle for demo. Hope it helps!
https://fiddle.jshell.net/pe25b0aa/8/

Comment: thanks!! ahh did not think to even do ng-repeats within ng-repeats, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can add `br` after item.mandatory , like this

```
<div ng-repeat="item in c.list track by $index">
{{item.mandatory}} <br>
</div>
```